# How will liquid nitrogen affect a steel instrument's ability to function?

Tags: thermodynamics, metallurgy

I want to retrieve cryotubes from the bottom of a liquid nitrogen freezer without taking all the freezer racks out and draining the liquid nitrogen. I think I can accomplish this using a tool like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/GrabEasy-Grabber-and-Retriever-PF0401/202505170) but I am not sure how well the tool will function at temperatures as low as -160 Celsius. Also, this particular tool is probably only about half as long as it needs to be.

Assuming I can find a longer version of such a tool, **how can I determine whether or not I need to be concerned about using to retrieve cryotubes from a liquid nitrogen freezer?** My main worry is that parts of the tool may become brittle and break or that the claw's ability grab may somehow become compromised. I am not concerned about the metal becoming excessively cold because I will be wearing gloves intended for such work.

Is there a chart or other resource that I can use to get a sense of metal's shear strength at cold temperatures?

Answer (score 2):

Metals become brittle as low temperature (and that's why you cool your Parr bomb in a dry ice bath, never in liquid nitrogen when you condense gases in).  But the worst thing that can happen is that a claw might break off, which shouldn't cause any damage to equipment.  Why not try in a small dewar first.  Liquid nitrogen is cheap.

A good alternative to racks of storage boxes are storage canes, such as [these](http://www.thermoscientific.com/en/product/storage-canes.html).

Comment: Thats a good idea to experiment in a small dewar first. 
I assume steel is a good metal for this kind of tool to be made of because its durable but I have no real understanding of how much variety there is to how brittle metals become in cold temperature or how quickly metals become brittle.